# Add hook after lsp-execute-code-action in doom-emacs

Tags: emacs, scala-metals

I work in doom-emacs with LSP-metals(scala LSP client).

My inconvenience is when I execute action I need additional action saving the buffer to trigger LSP-server for recompilation and show an updated errors list.
For example, import needed class [image]
I've tried to add the hook to `lsp-execute-code-action` but without success.

```
(add-hook 'lsp--execute-code-action 'save-current-buffer)
```